# Laravel 5: how to reset builtin throttle / ratelimiter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, rate-limiting, throttling

Im using Laravel's builtin throttle like this:

```
//File: Kernal
protected $middlewareGroups = [
'api' => ['throttle:10,3']
];
```

However, I would like to reset the count after certain action in one of my controllers (for example after successful login).

I can see this middleware uses `RateLimiter` and that has a public method called `clear`.

The problem is, how to use this? Because it depends upon the `key` from `ThrottleRequests` middleware.

1. To get the `object` of `ThrottleRequests` I need instance of `RateLimiter`
2. To get the object of `RateLimiter`, I need instance of `Cache`.
   .
   .

all in all, there is no end to how to use it..
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As your question is tagged with Laravel v5.5, here's what applies there:

### For Login attempts specifically:

You can [use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#login-throttling), so you would have access to the [`clearLoginAttempts`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.html#method_clearLoginAttempts) method, which calls the `clear()` method on the `RateLimiter` instance with the correct key without the need to provide the key.

Actually if you look at how `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins::clearLoginAttempts()` is implemented, you can see that the right key can be retrieved by `$this->throttleKey($request)`, once your controller uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

### In general:

You can always get the [`Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.html) instance by using `app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)`, which would in turn contain all the configured limiters and the cache as well. The problem is that it is not possible to get the cache keys from this point of view. So you really have to find out where and how the key was set in the first place, so you can use the same key for the reset.

The standard [`ThrottleRequests`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html) middleware sets the key in the [`handle()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html#method_handle) method, but the actual key would depend on where and how your throttling is configured (e.g.: is it a named limiter or only set using the numeric parameters, was `->by(...)` called on it to set the key explicitly etc.)

If you only need to find the key for one particular limiter, probably you can set a breakpoint in the `handle()` method and just check.

### Your case

In your particular case, as it is not a named limiter, the `handle()` method will call [`resolveRequestSignature`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.html#method_resolveRequestSignature) to get the key. I don't think you can easily access the Middleware instance from a Controller. What you can do is to check how that method generates the key and basically copy that piece of code to replicate the same keys, but I'd not recommend that as it is a dirty and fragile solution.
Ifyou check, you'll see the key can be reproduced as something like:

```php
if ($user = $request->user()) {
    $key = sha1($user->getAuthIdentifier());
}
elseif ($route = $request->route()) {
    $key = sha1($route->getDomain().'|'.$request->ip());
}
```

But in more recent Laravel versions you can explicitly set the key which is much cleaner and reliable solution:

---

### In Laravel 8

Now as the question is fairly old, most people would rather use the latest version of Laravel (v8 as of 2021/02/12), so for them the [documentation includes the way to "segment" the limiters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#segmenting-rate-limits) aka. become able to apply separate limit counters for different requests based on the request (or session data, etc.). In fact the `by()` method actually sets the `key` of the limiter. So you can set up one or more named limiters like:

```php
RateLimiter::for('my_per_ip_limiter', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perMinute(100)->by($request->ip());
});
```

This means the limiter named `my_per_ip_limiter` will use the IP as the key, so any time in your controllers you could call:

```php
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear($request->ip());
```

to reset the limiter for a particular IP. Or to get the number of attempts so far:

```php
$attempts_so_far = app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->attempts($request->ip());
```

Indeed instead of IP you could use any variable of the request (or session or whatever).

However there is no way (I think) to differentiate between the named limiters. So if the same key is used for another limiter as well, their hits will be counted together* and clear together. So giving a name like `my_per_ip_limiter` to the limiter is only useful so you can assign that limiter to particular routes by the name, e.g.:

```php
Route::post( 'login', 'Auth\LoginController@login' )
       ->middleware('throttle:my_per_ip_limiter');
```

But if you really need named limiters to reset individually, you have to use a unique key, for example prefixing it with something, e.g.:

```php
RateLimiter::for('my_other_ip_limiter', function (Request $request) {
    return Limit::perMinute(100)->by('other_'.$request->ip());
});
```

This can be cleared independently from the other one:

```php
// reset my_other_ip_limiter, but not my_per_ip_limiter :
app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear('other_'.$request->ip());
```

*: By counted together I mean they would add up, so if you apply two of them to the same request, each single request will bump the counter by 2!

Comment: it doesnt work with `app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear($request->ip());` and `$attempts_so_far = app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->attempts($request->ip());` I always get 0 for `$attempts_so_far`. May I know what's the issue here? Please help.

Comment: Your rate limiter probably uses a different key, not `$request->ip()`. As I said if you want to use `$request->ip()` as the key, you must manually configure your Rate Limiter with that key as described in the example above.
Generally the key depends on your configuration.
If you are using Laravel defaults, your key is probably `sha1($user->getAuthIdentifier())` for logged in users and `sha1($route->getDomain().'|'.$request->ip())` for everyone else. You must use one of these instead of `$request->ip()` in your calls. Or use a debugger to identify the correct key.

Comment: can't seem to make it work with this solution this is an example app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear('stop_'.$request->ip()); and also tried the resetattempts method but no luck is there something I could be missing?

Comment: @EvaCheong RateLimiter has appended limiter name (here is my_per_ip_limiter) to the key and pass it to md5(), so you should do it manually before passing the key to clear().

For example:

RateLimiter::clear(md5('my_per_ip_limiter' . $request->ip()));

Comment: on laravel 8, hashing was being used. So to reset the Rate Limiter you should use app(\Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::class)->clear(md5('my_other_ip_limiterother_'.$request->ip()));  if you want to reset my_other_ip_limit